# Dynamic parameters in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Looking for a solution to dynamically update the parameter in tableau, so that it populates new/changed values, automatically, once the data is refreshed. 
Just fyi, Currently, my parameter is getting values from a field which has got date values in string format(for eg: 2016Q1).
Request help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible without serious XML hacking and scripting. There have been multiple requests for this feature from Tableau users, and it might be added in the future.